# Java Concurrency - Adding a Shutdown hook before calling `ExecutorService#execute`

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a runnable thread `MyDesiredRunnable` which has the following run:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        this.process();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        isAlive.set(false);
    }
}
```

`isAlive` is an `AtomicBoolean`.

The Scheduler:

```
// Class definition bla bla bla
   private final ExecutorService exth = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void schedule() {
    Runnable r = new MyDesiredRunnable();
    Runnable sdt = ()->{MyDesiredRunnable.isAlive.set(false);};

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(sdt));
    this.exth.execute(r);
}
```

This Scheduler will always be only one instance. My question is, "Does it matter if I add the shutdown hook before I call `execute`. All I can understand from javadocs is that the shutdown hook will not be resolved until JVM shutodown is commanded. Also, the `execute` command also doesn't seem to say anything against having a shutdown hook before/after. It's just that a few of `ExecutorService` examples on SO or even some books have the shutdownhook registration happening after we call execute. So I just wanted to know whether there is a "Catch" that I don't understand.

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of catching a specific Exception, why not set `false` in a `finally` block so only System.exit will prevent it being set.

Comment: the JVM can be stopped just before execute is called, so the shutdown hook will be called even if the desired runnable is not. But since the shutdown hook is *only* setting the AtomicBoolean (in thtat case), this is not a problem. (Could be a problem if freeing resources that are only created in the runnable - probably a wrong usage of a shutdown hook)

Comment: I suppose the only advantage to having the shutdown hook added first is that in the unlikely event that the JVM shuts down precisely between the two statements, you are guaranteed that the shutdown hook will be executed. That said, what is even the point of setting a boolean field when the JVM is about to terminate?

Comment: @PeterLawrey    Fair point! I wasn't in a good mood to craft the `try-catch-finally` setup, but yes you are right. Why not :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid trying to detect if the task is running indirectly you can use the Thread itself. If the thread isn't alive, your task isn't running.

```
class ThreadedRunnable implements Runnable {
    volatile boolean started = false;
    volatile Thread thread;
    Runnable runnable;

    ThreadedRunnable(Runnable runnable) { this.runnable = runnable; }

    public void run() {
        thread = Thread.currentThread();
        started = true;
        try {
            runnable.run();
        } catch (Throwable t) { // don't silently discard it
            logger.error(runnable + " died", t);
        } finally {
            thread = null;
        }
    }

    public String state() { // or return an Enum
        Thread t = thread;
        return !started ? "not started" :
               t == null || !t.isAlive() ? "finished" : "running";
    }
}
```